# Why do I only need to loop 23 times to draw 24 rectangles?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I've just encountered a strange behavior of the for loop and can't find an explanation.

I have a 2D game with this logical element which is a field.

```
//Declaration of the JPanel logical size. 
private int[][] grid = new int[24][12];
```

Number of rows is 24, right?

I am painting this grid using this:

```
   for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++ ) 
        for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++)
```

Then I decided not to paint the last row and did this:

```
r < grid.length - 1;
```

nothing happened. I thought maybe I need parentheses. I added them and it still didn't work.
Then I changed it to

```
r < grid.length - 2;
```

And under this condition the last row was not painted as I originally wanted.

But now I am confused because mathematically: grid.length - 2 = 22; r < 22 means r(max) == 21 which means I am supposed to have two rows not painted. What am I missing?

#### Test case:

```
class Action extends JPanel {
   public static final int FRAME_SIZE_X = 370;
   public static final int FRAME_SIZE_Y = 720;
   private int[][] grid = new int[24][12];

  public Action() { //Setting everything for JPanel
     Dimension actionDimension = new Dimension(360, 690); 
     setPreferredSize(actionDimension); 
     setVisible(true); 
     //...
  }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
     super.paintComponent(pen);
     for (int r = 0; r < grid.length - 2; r++) //Line with a problem
       for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {

         // [set up pen, etc.]

         // draw line
         pen.drawRect(c * 30, r * 30, FRAME_SIZE_X / 12, FRAME_SIZE_Y / 24);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: There must be something else. This should work as expected.

Comment: don't you want `grid[r].length` instead of `grid[c].length`?

Comment: You should paint your grid with `grid[r].length;` instead of c i think..

Comment: Nope, in this case I don't paint the column. I am talking about the rows.

Comment: That [shouldn't make a difference](https://ideone.com/JBLuqf). Every row has the exact same amount of columns, `grid[r]` has the same length as `grid[c]`.

Comment: Looping a 2D array is hard stuff :) You're not showing all the relevant code, I believe.

Comment: @user3081519: show the code you're using to do this, obviously the code itself is wrong since my ideone sample demonstrates that it works as intended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's late, and I know nothing about JPanel in any case, but...

> ```
> public static final int FRAME_SIZE_X = 370;
> public static final int FRAME_SIZE_Y = 720;
> ```

...

> ```
> Dimension actionDimension = new Dimension(360, 690);
> ```

Pretty sure your panel is exactly one row (30 units) shorter than your frame - so even if you're looping 24 times and rendering 24 rows, the last one's getting clipped since there's only room for 23 rows on the screen.

Expand the panel to a height of 720 (or more), and I'll bet you notice the difference between 23 and 24 rows...

Comment: Another argument in favor of distilling code listings down to the smallest possible example is that it makes it a lot easier to see bugs... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Take out a piece of paper, and draw a nice large rectangle on it. This is your JPanel. For the sake of this example, we're going to turn grid length into 3.

Take out a different color pen, and draw your first rectangle. This should go from the top left corner to the top right corner, down a third of the JPanel, back across, and back to the top left corner.

Now draw your second rectangle. We'll start a third of the JPanel down, go across to the right, go down another third, back across, and back up to where we started.

Now for the third one. But you'll notice you don't actually need to draw it. Why? The two sides and the bottom are already drawn by the JPanel, and the top is the same line as the bottom of the immediately prior row.

So while yes, another rectangle is drawn by Swing, you just don't see it because every line that it draws has already been drawn by something else. Likewise, to remove the last row, you need to stop drawing the last two rows. (You'll notice on your piece of paper that you get two rows only if you draw one rectangle.)

Note that if you change pen color between drawing your JPanel and your rows, it's a lot easier to see the problem.

Comment: What a great example!

Comment: That would be a good explanation in case if I have a one-dimensional array. But I have a 2D array. Continuing with your example... draw two vertical lines on that picture. You will get 3 squares within every rectangle. If I don't paint the last row - the vertical lines that separate rectangle into squares simply don't get drawn. I appreciate your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++ )
```

If `grid.length` is 24, that iterates 24 times. You're forgetting about the zero. Or else your observations are awry.

Comment: I know you don't have to, but if you take a look at the version of the question before it was edited by moderators you would be able to find a code that contains a bit more detail and compiles, you will be able to observe the very same thing that I do.